# Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints - while trying to adjust dynamically cell height

Tags: swift, uitableview, constraints

I would like to adjust a cell dynamically to show all text which I have provided to a label inside of this particular cell. I have a custom cell and it cuts me the text and shows 3 dots at the end.

While trying this in viewdidload:

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = tableView.rowHeight
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

a) it destroys me the whole layout

b) shows me this error msg:

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7faa6a5ab2f0 H:[UIImageView:0x7faa6a5ad100(135)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7faa6a5b9af0 UIImageView:0x7faa6a5ad100.leading == UITableViewCellContentView:0x7faa6a5acba0.leadingMargin>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7faa6a5b9c80 UILabel:0x7faa6a5b3f00'Mercedes-Benz G500 4x4\U00b2 s...'.trailing == UITableViewCellContentView:0x7faa6a5acba0.trailingMargin>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7faa6a5b9d20 H:[UIImageView:0x7faa6a5ad100]-(8)-[UILabel:0x7faa6a5b3f00'Mercedes-Benz G500 4x4\U00b2 s...']>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7faa6a5c09c0 'fittingSizeHTarget' H:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x7faa6a5acba0(34)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7faa6a5ab2f0 H:[UIImageView:0x7faa6a5ad100(135)]>
```

Is there a way to check out from this error message whats the matter here?

Comment: Haha, OK. Nice answer. Is there a chance for normal people to decrypt the error message? What does it say in regular language? Is the problem the constraint between the label and the image?

Comment: Working on it, hang in there.

Comment: The error message shows only _horizontal_ constaints. What _vertical_ constraints do you have, i.e. constraints that determine the _height_ of the cell?

Comment: Also: In the storyboard, is there any warning / error from Interface Builder about your constraints? You _must_ resolve these before trying to run the project.

Comment: Here are all my constraints: http://s4.postimg.org/q7c3dfcfh/constraints.jpg
/edit: No waring, no error, nothing...

Comment: Okay, but those constraints make no sense. Only one subview has both a top and a bottom constraint: the label on the right. And you have not given it any height constraint. So when the app runs, it is going to collapse vertically - and thus, so will the cell. You have _drawn_ the cell as being tall, but it is not going to _be_ tall. It's going to shrink and cut off the visibility of the image.

Comment: Is there a proposal from your side? Is exactly what you described with the collapse. Or a good tutorial for noobs in this case...

Comment: Well, I'm not sure what outcome you are trying to get. But if you want the label not to collapse, you should be adding a height constraint to that label.